# Island with population 20

Tags: combinatorics

> Consider an imaginary island with a population of 20 people.10 of these people know carpentry,10 of them are painters and 10 of them are shoemaker.We call a group of 3 people as "Jack of all trades" if at least one of them knows carpentry,at least one of them knows painting and at least one of them is shoemaker.What's the number of "Jack of all trades" groups in this island?

It's obvious that this problem involves inclusion-exclusion principle,but the number of unknowns is itself a problem!
Maybe the question lacks some information(Source: a math contest in Iran).
Many thanks to all people discussing this problem:)

Comment: Can you solve it for smaller populations like 4 or 5 or 6 and see if there's a pattern?

Comment: Anyway, it's not clear to me that there's enough information here to answer the problem, if you don't know how many know each pair of trades, and how many know all three trades.

Comment: This problem has been given in a Math contest in Iran as a multiple choice question with the following choices: 120,380,570,1020 and 1140.But somehow I agree with you

Comment: I just translated the question as precise as possible.No extra info had been given!

Comment: I did three cases.  1140 = ${20 \choose 3}$ is no possible.  If 10 know all three the answer 1020 which is one of the choices.  If 15 know one skill and 5 know all the the answer is 290 which is not.  So... I'm perplexed.  I think I could argue 1020 is the most and 290 is the least (maybe) but I don't how to rule any others out.

Answer (score 2):

If the question can be answered, then the answer must not depend on how the three groups of 10 overlap. Therefore, we can answer it assuming it's the same 10 people who build, paint, and make shoes. That answer is $\binom{20}{3}-\binom{10}{3}=1020$.

To get more information about whether this answer could possibly be correct, universally, we can look at a different arrangement. Suppose that the same 10 people build and paint, while the other 10 make shoes. Now the number of Jack-of-all-Trades groups is $\binom{10}{2}\times 10 = 450$.

Clearly, the answer depends on information which is not given, so the question as posed cannot be answered.

Comment: This problem has been given in a Math contest in Iran as a multiple choice question with the following choices: 120,380,570,1020 and 1140

Comment: Not $10\choose 3 $ but ${20\choose 3}-{10\choose3} $.

Comment: The first answer isn't right.  If 10 know all three you only need to pick one of those, not all 3, to satisfy the condition.  So that ${20 \choose 3} - {10 \choose 3} =1020$.

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Fixed that.